# How to convert certain characters in a sentence using if else statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

my program so far only works if you enter one letter. How would I alter the program so it works with a complete sentence?

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string to be converted: ");
        String convert = input.nextLine();

        if(convert.equals("a")){
            System.out.print("@"); 
        }

            else{
                if(convert.equals("e")){
                    System.out.print("$");
                }
```

An example:

Enter the string to be converted: **abcde**

The converted string is: @bcd$

Comment: Please add a text description of your problem to your question. Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Your code reads complete line. you can check by printing convert value. However, as you are using the .equals method then it will check for `@` only. You can use the .contains method which will check if there is `@` in your input string

Comment: @NomadMaker , I have edited my post to show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will work only for an input consisting of one character e.g. if you input `a`, it will print `@` and if you input `e`, it will print `$` and so on (if you add other vowels too in your program). It is because you are comparing (and replacing) the whole input string rather than comparing (and replacing) the character(s) of the input string.

There are many ways in which you can do it. A couple of them are as follows:

1. Get an array of characters out of the input string and then iterate the array to process the printing as per your requirement e.g.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Enter the string to be converted: ");
           String convert = input.nextLine();
           for (char ch : convert.toCharArray()) {
               switch (ch) {
               case 'a':
                   System.out.print('@');
                   break;
               case 'e':
                   System.out.print('$');
                   break;
               case 'i':
                   System.out.print('^');
                   break;
               case 'o':
                   System.out.print('*');
                   break;
               case 'u':
                   System.out.print('&');
                   break;
               default:
                   System.out.print(ch);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run**:

   ```
   Enter the string to be converted: coronavirus
   c*r*n@v^r&s
   ```
2. Replace the characters as per your requirements using [String::replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) e.g.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Enter the string to be converted: ");
           String convert = input.nextLine();
           convert = convert.replace('a', '@').replace('e', '$').replace('i', '^').replace('o', '*').replace('u', '&');
           System.out.println(convert);
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run:**

   ```
   Enter the string to be converted: coronavirus
   c*r*n@v^r&s
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this instead of your if sentences:

```
for (int i = 0; i < convert.length(); i++ { //This loop will repeat the same times that the String's lenght
    switch (convert.charAt(i) {
        case 'a': System.out.print("@");
            break;
        case 'e': System.out.print("$");
            break;
        case 'i': System.out.print("&");
            break;
        case 'o': System.out.print("#"); // Here you put the letter to replace.
            break;
        default: // This code will execute if there's a option you didn't put on the cases
    }
}
```

Comment: It will fail as you have used `"a"` instead of `'a'` (similarly for other cases).

Comment: You have put a `char` in `switch` but you are comparing a `String` in `case`. I hope, you understand your mistake now.